# dataframe export to excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, export

please can someone help. I want to export % change values from values (in bold) into excel. but I get message

KeyError: "Not all names specified in 'columns' are found"

```py
import pandas as pd
# import openpyxl module
#import openpyxl
import numpy as np

# Give the location of the file
path = 'C:/Users/a1b.xlsx'
df= pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols=['Date','name', 'myname', 'fx'])
ds= pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols=['Date'])
df2= pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols=['Date','name1', 'myname1', 'fx1'])
#print (df2)
df3= df.copy()


df[['name','myname','fx']] = df[['name','myname','fx']].pct_change(periods = 5)

**a= df2[np.array(df)> np.array(df2)]**

print (a)



a.to_excel(''C:/Users/a1b.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet3',startcol=2,index=False,columns= ['Date','name', 'myname', 'fx'])
```

I was expecting values from a= df2[np.array(df)> np.array(df2)]

Comment: df2 has no columns `name` or `myname` or `fx`

Answer (score 0):

what I am looking is to return only the rows whwere array (df)> array (df2)
however in excel I see every single row returned. is there a way pls
a= df2[np.array(df)> np.array(df2)]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).